Is it possible to run the costmap node alone in navigation2?
In ubuntu 22.04, ROS2 humble environment,
I'm trying to use my own path planner.
So I want to run the costmap isolated with other nav2 nodes such as controller server, planner server, behavior server or etc. From the source code, it seems the local costmap and global costmap is initialized and generated at controller and planner server, but I would like to isolate it and don't want to use navigation2 nodes as possible i can.
Following code is code i have made it, but it has a problem with inflation layer and static layer.
The map is publishing for static layer, but it keep makes following error
[local_costmap_node-2] [WARN] [1726038637.542430701] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Can't update static costmap layer, no map received
At first, i thought it's a problem with reading a yaml file or something, but I have added obstacle layer and it works, so it's not a yaml file error.
Any recommendation to solve this error?
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "nav2_costmap_2d/costmap_2d_ros.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"
#include <memory>

class LocalCostmapNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    LocalCostmapNode()
        : Node("local_costmap_node")
    {
        // Declare parameters for the costmap and layers
        this->declare_parameter("always_send_full_costmap", false);
        this->declare_parameter("footprint", std::string("[]"));
        this->declare_parameter("footprint_padding", 0.01);
        this->declare_parameter("global_frame", "odom");
        this->declare_parameter("robot_base_frame", "base_link");
        this->declare_parameter("update_frequency", 5.0);
        this->declare_parameter("publish_frequency", 1.0);
        this->declare_parameter("rolling_window", true);
        this->declare_parameter("resolution", 0.05);
        this->declare_parameter("width", 10.0);
        this->declare_parameter("height", 10.0);
        this->declare_parameter("origin_x", 0.0);
        this->declare_parameter("origin_y", 0.0);
        this->declare_parameter("lethal_cost_threshold", 100);
        this->declare_parameter("track_unknown_space", false);
        this->declare_parameter("transform_tolerance", 0.3);
        this->declare_parameter("unknown_cost_value", 255);
        this->declare_parameter("plugins", std::vector<std::string>{"static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"});
        this->declare_parameter("clearable_layers", std::vector<std::string>{"obstacle_layer", "voxel_layer"});

        // Static Layer parameters
        this->declare_parameter("static_layer.plugin", "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer");
        this->declare_parameter("static_layer.map_topic", "/costmap");  // Change to typical map topic
        this->declare_parameter("static_layer.subscribe_to_updates", true);

        // Obstacle Layer parameters
        this->declare_parameter("obstacle_layer.plugin", "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer");
        this->declare_parameter("obstacle_layer.observation_sources", "laser_scan_sensor");
        this->declare_parameter("obstacle_layer.laser_scan_sensor.data_type", "LaserScan");
        this->declare_parameter("obstacle_layer.laser_scan_sensor.topic", "/scan1");
        this->declare_parameter("obstacle_layer.laser_scan_sensor.clearing", true);
        this->declare_parameter("obstacle_layer.laser_scan_sensor.marking", true);
        this->declare_parameter("obstacle_layer.max_obstacle_height", 2.0);
        this->declare_parameter("obstacle_layer.obstacle_range", 2.5);
        this->declare_parameter("obstacle_layer.raytrace_range", 3.0);

        // Inflation Layer parameters
        this->declare_parameter("inflation_layer.plugin", "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer");
        this->declare_parameter("inflation_layer.inflation_radius", 0.55);
        this->declare_parameter("inflation_layer.cost_scaling_factor", 10.0);

        // Initialize and configure the local costmap
        local_costmap_ros_ = std::make_shared<nav2_costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS>(
            "local_costmap", this->get_namespace(), "local_costmap");

        // Load the layers and activate them
        local_costmap_ros_->configure();
        local_costmap_ros_->activate();

        // Check if the layers were added successfully
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Local costmap node initialized with frames: %s -> %s",
                    this->get_parameter("global_frame").as_string().c_str(),
                    this->get_parameter("robot_base_frame").as_string().c_str());

        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Inflation layer configured with radius: %f",
                    this->get_parameter("inflation_layer.inflation_radius").as_double());
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<nav2_costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS> local_costmap_ros_;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    auto node = std::make_shared<LocalCostmapNode>();
    rclcpp::spin(node);
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}

I have updated my launch file to run the node.
without activating lifecycle, it doesn't work
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import LifecycleNode
from launch.actions import TimerAction, ExecuteProcess
def generate_launch_description():
local_costmap_config = '/home/home/mmando_ws/src/costmap_generator/config/local_costmap.yaml'
# Define the lifecycle node with proper name 'local_costmap'
local_costmap_node = LifecycleNode(
    package='nav2_costmap_2d',
    executable='nav2_costmap_2d',
    name='local_costmap',  # Correct node name
    namespace='',  # No namespace needed
    output='screen',
    parameters=[local_costmap_config],
)

# Command to configure the node
configure_command = TimerAction(
    period=5.0,
    actions=[ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=['ros2', 'lifecycle', 'set', '/local_costmap', 'configure'],
        output='screen'
    )]
)

# Command to activate the node after configure
activate_command = TimerAction(
    period=10.0,
    actions=[ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=['ros2', 'lifecycle', 'set', '/local_costmap', 'activate'],
        output='screen'
    )]
)

return LaunchDescription([
    local_costmap_node,
    configure_command,
    activate_command
])


There is already a standalone ROS node for costmaps, you don't need to write anything new.
ros2 run nav2_costmap_2d nav2_costmap_2d


Thank you for your answer
It's an honor to get your answer
I have made a launch file to change the name of the node, but it doesn't changes
Also seems it has problems with reading yaml file.
Any suggestion?
I have updated my launch file to the post
thank you

from your suggestion, it works only i activate with following commands
ros2 lifecycle set /costmap/costmap configure
ros2 lifecycle set /costmap/costmap activate

Yes, it is a lifecycle node
